# Navigator.pop(context) pops the route instead of the bottomSheet [web3modal_flutter]

Tags: flutter, wallet-connect, web3modal

In Flutter using package [web3modal_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/web3modal_flutter), I am opening the bottom sheet for wallet selection. When closing the bottom sheet the package pops the route where I am currently on instead of closing the bottom sheet.

```
@RoutePage()
class CreateWalletQuickFundPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CreateWalletQuickFundPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userBloc = context.read<UserBloc>();

    return PageWrapper(
      cubit: ConnectWalletCubit(context.read<UserBloc>()),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 32),
            BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return WalletQrCode(wallet: state.selectedWallet!);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 32),
            Text(
              context.l10n.welcomeToYourNewWallet,
              style: context.typography.heading2,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 14),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 290),
              child: Text(
                context.l10n.thisIsYourPersonalBankVaultForTokens,
                style: context.typography.text14,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            BlocBuilder<ConnectWalletCubit, ConnectWalletState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                final connectWalletCubit = context.read<ConnectWalletCubit>();

                return Button(
                  onTap: () async {
                    await connectWalletCubit.w3mService.openModal(context);
                  },
                  text: context.l10n.fundYourWallet,
                  activeColor: context.colors.moonGreen,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[bottom sheet with route closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROKPX.png)

When I call the same function for opening the bottom sheet on a dialog, it works as it should. But I don't see and difference.

When pressing the "X" button on the bottoms sheet the package calls the Navigator.pop(context) with the context provided in `await connectWalletCubit.w3mService.openModal(context);` My guess is it is something wrong with the context provided, but am not sure since everything in code seems right.

If i create my own bottom sheet like this which is using the same context it also work like it should, so I don't get it

```
    showBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) =>
        const SelectNetworkBottomSheet(),
    );
```

Comment: Try wrapping the class with a [`Builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) widget and use _that_ `BuildContext`. See if that helps.

Comment: Tried using Builder, but it is the same effect, it just pops the route since the Builder and the BuildContext are still coming from the CreateWalletQuickFundPage